# coc-pyright is using buffers irresponsibly

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, python

I've been noticing that my buffer number increases really fast without me even using them. I rely on buffers quite a lot to switch between files, and it's really annoying when I open a second file and it's loaded into buffer 603.

I finally tracked down the issue to `coc-pyright`. When I disable the plugin, the buffers behave as I expect. I can't figure out why this plugin is increasing the buffers so quickly, but it seems like every time there's a window of information displayed, it uses and destroys a buffer to do so. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

I'm using nvim 0.7.2.

Comment: sounds like you already found out the culprit. In that case, please create an issue at the plugins issue tracker

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt that does sound like the obvious thing to do now. Not sure what I was thinking. I guess I just assumed there is some random Vim setting like `:set disablehiddenbuffers=4` that I had set wrong.

Comment: Submitted here: https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues/905

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted the issue to the `coc-pyright` project: https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues/905

Hopefully an answer is given there.